# Не работает графика

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
The method drawLine(int,int,int,int) is undefined for the type Graphics
```

Раньше работав код)Сейчас нет.Вроде все верно...

Comment: Ошибку какую выдает? Наведите на красный крестик и скопипастите сюда. Вангую отсутствие необходимого импорта

Comment: The method drawLine(int,int,int,int) is undefined for the type Graphics

Answer (score 3):

У вас в проекте уже есть класс Graphics.Соответственно, в нём нет нужного вам метода.В таком случае вам стоит явно указать путь к классу Graphics, то есть прописать java.awt.Graphics.Итого, сигнатура вашего метода должна выглядеть примерно вот так: `public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g)`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит нам, что у вас в классе `Graphics` отсутствует метод `drawLine(int,int,int,int)`

Но я, так же, не вижу в самом верху строки

```
import Graphics;
```

Comment: этот класс входит в пакет java.awt

Comment: А зачем он в проекте присутствует отдельно? Не может эклипсу от этого голову сносить?

Comment: Да, судя по всему, пытается использоваться класс рядом с Zadacha1, вместо класса из пакета awt